# Why does NuGet uses %APPDATA%\Roaming\packages as repository folder despite configuration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

For some reason my NuGet package are added to .csproj file based on `%APPDATA%\Roaming\packages` folder and it causes my project not to build via build server. I have checked the configuration in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\.nuge\NuGet.config`, there `repositoryPath` is set to `..\packages`. I checked `%programfiles(x86)\Nuget\Config` folder there is no configuration related to `globalPackagesFolder`.  Would someone please let me know why my packages are restored in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\packages` folder and how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Is there another NuGet.config file used by your solution? Otherwise the behaviour seems correct. Paths are relative to the NuGet.Config file so `..\packages` in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\.nuget\NuGet.config` would point to the `%APPDATA%\Roaming\packages` directory.

Comment: @MattWard, you and Perry are right, there was due to path being relative to my NuGet.config. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does NuGet uses %APPDATA%\Roaming\packages as repository folder
> despite configuration?

The problem is in the global `%APPDATA%\Roaming\.nuget\NuGet.config` file. In the default `nuget.config` file, you should not set `repositoryPath` path. It will use the default [repositoryPath path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section)(`solution folder\packages\`).

If you add a new repositoryPath path(..\packages) in `nuget.config` file, it will enable the new reference package path based on the relative path setting `..\packages`.

So the behavior appears and your project references the path `%APPDATA%\Roaming\packages`.

**Solution**

If you want it back to use the default path, you can try it:

**1)** close VS, enter `%APPDATA%\Roaming\.nuget\NuGet.config` file, delete it:

```
<add key="repositoryPath" value="..\packages" />
```

If you have add a key called `globalPackagesFolder` and do not want to use it, you can also delete that node.

When you delete it, then you can use the default `repositoryPath`.

**2)** then test it in another new project and I am sure that this will go away.

**Besides**, if you delete it in `%APPDATA%\Roaming\.nuget\NuGet.config` and does not work, you should check whether you have a custom `nuget.config` in your solution folder or any Parent directories,if so, you should check the file and delete such node in it. See [NuGet.Config file location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior).

Comment: Thank you Perry Qian. Your fix solved my issue. Excellent.